# Codeigniter form validation multiple callbacks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to do the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:login_username', 'callback_login_check');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:login_username', 'callback_employee_location_check');
```

I wouldn't get a valuation error, but this condition was always TRUE:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

If I change the above 2 lines to:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:login_username', 'callback_login_check|callback_employee_location_check');
```

Then it works as expected. Why can't I use the first form? Does the second one overwrite the first and the login check never gets called?

Comment: What values does your callbacks return?

Comment: booleans (TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: Ok, so one of the callbacks returns false? If that is the case then run() will return false as one of your rules failed. In the second where you OR the callbacks together it looks like it gets TRUE OR FALSE which is going to return true. You can debug that by running line 1, and then running line 2 independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, when you combine both callbacks inside the set_rules() it works. This is correct. If you enter them in seperatly they overwrite one another. All rules for the form input need to be in the same set_rules() method.