# Codeigniter - adding multiple custom validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is it possible to add 2 or more custom validation functions using the same field?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('myfield', 'My Field','required|my_method1|my_method2');
```

> eg. my_method1 check the string format and my_method2 check the existence of the string in my database.

Seems like just the first method works and the second one is ignored. Is it because i'm using the same parameter for both functions?

thanks.

Comment: Can we see the two methods you are using for validation?

Comment: please put your functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can!

In each `my_method_N($x)` function, you must inform them as prefix the name `callback_`, for instance: `callback_my_function1|callback_my_function2`.

Take a look at this question that explains how you can use multiple callback functions and the syntax in the manual.

[Codeigniter form validation multiple callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334426/codeigniter-form-validation-multiple-callbacks)

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form_validation#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods